# Print Single Value Of Multi Dimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, 3d

I am using following array

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
     (
        [id] => 6
        [key] => SITE_NAME
        [value] => Webg Smarty CMS Small
        [name] => general
        [title] => website name
        [type] => text
)

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 32
        [key] => PHONE_NUMBER
        [value] => 713-332-4675 
        [name] => general
        [title] => Phone Number
        [type] => text
    )

)
```

I want to show [0][value], [1][value]

I am using foreach but i am unable to print values

how to show it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//$arr = your nested array aboe 
foreach($arr as $v){
  echo $v['value']; //this will print 'Webg Smarty CMS Small' first in your example followed by '713-332-4675'
}

$arr[0]['value'] will give you 'Webg Smarty CMS Small'
$arr[1]['value'] will give you '713-332-4675'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($yourArr as $key => $value)
{
  echo $value['value'];
}
```

OR

```
echo $yourArr[0]['value'];  //print value of first element
echo $yourArr[0]['key'];    //print key of first element
```

Comment: I tried this but it is printing all values i want to show only single value like [0][value], [1][key]

Comment: It can't print all values. It print only `value`

Comment: yes but i want to echo each value with differnt style like <div class="phone">[1][value]</div>, <div class="title">[0][value]</div>

Comment: how to echo $yourArr[0]['value']; ??

Comment: how to display it in smarty template??

Comment: Sorry! I dont now `smarty template`.